# How to migrate products changes after delta migration from m1 to m2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I have done data migration from m1 to m2, after that changes have been made in m1 products. Now i want to migrate product changes from m1 to m2. I have done delta migration but as we know it doesn't update the existing products changes. Any help or advice will be appricated.

Comment: run this command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: hi @Arjun, did you use delta migration? does it worked?